# Algorithm to recreate a complex order

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am having trouble do devise an algorithm for a operation and I would like to ask for help. Since this is rather abstract, this is pseudo-C# only.

I have a List of Objects, which are in a List:

```
Object A
Object B
Object C
```

This list comes from a storage area, but the User can create new elements in the List through two methods: copying an Object or merging two bojects together. 
So, after a user interaction the List might look like this:

```
Object A
Object A1 - Clone of A
Object B
Object C
Object BC - Merge of B and C
```

Each new object stores it's "parent(s)", so it is possibly to track down the source of each object. 
But it is possible to chain copy and combine methods, so the third generation might look like this:

```
Object A
Object A1 - Clone of A
Object B
Object A1B - Merge of A1 and B
Object A1B2 - Cloe onf A1b
Object C
Object BC - Merge of B and C
Object BC2 - Clone of BC
```

And now I am stuck: Sometimes this list has to be regenarated from the storage in Example 1. While it is easy to recreate the "plain" copied or merged Objects, I am unable to think of a good algorithm to indentify the order, in which combinations have to be recreated.
Look at iteration 3: To recreate A1B2 I have to clone A1 first, then merge A1 and B to A1B and then clone this Object.
Is there some kind of algorithm, which can determine the necessary order?

Comment: How about `ABC`, is it `A + BC` or `AB + C`? And how do you differentiate `AB1` between `A(B1)` and `(AB)1` ?

Comment: Could be either one :( Depends on the Users-choice.
I store the Informaction on the immidiate Parnent, So ABC would know it's parents

Comment: If you know the parents, isn't this then a simple case of recursively looking at the parents, then reversing the order?

Comment: I'd suggest using RPN (Reversed Polish Notation) for coding clone and merge, e.g.: A1B2 == A'B+' (take A, clone it - I'v used apostroph ' for cloning operation, take B merge, finally clone); BC+ - merge B and C; BC+' - merge B and C then clone; B'C'+ - clone B, clone C, merge

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I thnik so. But the challenge whould be to find the "oldest" children...

Comment: @ChristianSauer I still don't get it. Why not start at the first element (Object A) and then step through the list in order? In the example, elements only depend on previous entries in the list so you should never reach a dead-end if you process sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

Your notation can be *ambiguous*:

```
  Object A
  Object B
  Object A1 - clone A
  Object B1 - clone B
  Object B2 - clone B1
  Object A1B2 - is it a merge of A1 and B2 or clone of A1B1?
```

I'd suggest using (at least internally) **RPN** (*Reversed Polish Notation*), 
let, for instance, operations be

```
  ' for clone 
  + for merge
```

So, e.g.

```
  A        - just A
  A'       - clone A
  A''      - clone A, then clone the result again
  AB+      - merge A and B
  A'B'+    - clone A, clone B, merge the clones
  A'B+'    - clone A, merge with B, clone the result
  AB'+C'+' - A merged with cloned B merged with cloned C and finally cloned
```

RPN is *unambiguous* and can be *easily transformed* (you can unfold RPN into tree) into any other 
representation

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I am unsure if that is really necessary. Internally all references are stored unambigously - that is a Object is either a clone or a merge. Both at the same time is impossible.
I am mainly concerned about the cases where are merge /clones are stacked on top of each other

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), which given a partial order (here on steps of the algorithm), establishes a total order that's consistent with the partial order.

To explain a bit more, you've got a list of targets and dependencies for each. For example (taking your own), "BC2" is a target, and you build it by cloning "BC". Thus a dependency for "BC2" is "BC", and thus, in the partial order, you'll have "BC" < "BC2".

Incidentally (to help understanding rather than suggestion as a practical approach to your problem) this is exactly the same problem that `make` solves. You would express this idea in a Makefile something like this:

```
BC2: BC
    clone BC > BC2
```

ie: BC2 depends on BC, and you build it by cloning BC (with a made-up example of a tool `clone`).

There's an example implementation of topological sort with further explanation on the wikipedia page linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I will give it a shot and report the progress ;)